# Adding push notifications to Parse server hosted on Heroku crashing

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have a simple Parse server hosted on Heroku, and I'm trying to setup Apple Push Notifications on it.

I have my .p12 file exported correctly, and I'm trying to add it into the index.js file.

Here is my that section of my `index.js` file: (all `XXX`'s are my sensitive data commented out just for this post, those sections are working correctly.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'XXX',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'XXX',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'XXX', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'XXX',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
}

push: {
    ios: {
        pfx: '/certs/lafcert.p12', // the path and filename to the .p12 file you exported earlier. 
        bundleId: 'XXX', // The bundle identifier associated with your app
        production: false // Specifies which environment to connect to: Production (if true) or Sandbox
    }
}
});
```

And Here is my server directory
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iktft.jpg

If I comment the whole `push: {}` section out, when I deploy to heroku the server launches correctly. However, if I uncomment it out, and I think all the information is correct, it gives me an application error, and refuses to load.

I don't know what to change about this, I can't think of anything else to do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I was missing a comma before the `push: {}` info.

Comment: Can you post your full index.js and main.js. I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your "pfx" should be: pfx: 'certificates/lafcert.p12'